# Can I use Apple Passcode for my App

Tags: iphone

I want to make one passcode for my app, can I use apple passcode for the same. I want to use Apple embedded Passcode for my app instead of passcode programming in my project, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, apple does not supply any API to use the iOS passcode.